# Как просто найти слово в тексте?

Tags: c#

upd: Дается текст. ( Top topfase ) Надо найти слово, и заменить его. Пусть надо заменить "Top" на "bottom". Результат -> Bottom topface

Искать подстроку, а потом смотреть, что рядом с ней стоит - по-моему, глупо. Искать видом IndexOf(" word ") - тоже не дело. Кто его знает, какие разделители попадутся.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пару вариантов:

1. Разделите текст на слова, учитывая ваши разделители. Потом в массиве слов найдите нужное.
2. Выделите слова из текста регуляркой типа `\w+`. Опять таки среди полученного списка найдите нужное слово.

Comment: Помимо нахождения слов, потом еще надо их заменить на иные. Т.е. из массива загонять обратно - муторно как-то.

Comment: Стоит описывать всю задачу сразу. Можно попробовать делать замену с помощью регулярок. Составляете регулярное выражение так, чтобы допустить символы-разделители перед и после слова. Что-то вроде `(\s*)(?<word>\w+)(\s*)`. И заменяете вхождения с помощью [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx).

Comment: Там ещё есть и границы слова `\b`.

Answer (score 2):

А причем разделители? Надо найти слово, например "привет". Ищем с помошью `IndexOf`. Можно регуляки использовать. Можно LINQ метод `Contains` который просто возвращает `bool`. Или я вопроса не понял?

**UPDATE:**

Если без регулярок то:
[C# string replace tо match whole words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605299/c-sharp-string-replace-to-match-whole-words)

Там есть пример кода, которые делает поиск и замену слова.

Comment: Ваше решение найдет также часть слова "приветов".

Comment: Ну тогда только регулярками, либо перечислять все разделители и передавать в метод `Split`

Answer (score 2):

Когда-то давно применяли вот такую хитрость:

1. Берем исходную строку "top topface" и добавляем по пробелу(в данном случае. в обобщенном - разделитель слов) с каждой стороны, получаем при этом " top topface "
2. Если нужно заменить "top" на "bottom" то ищем вхождения " top " в строку и меняем его на " bottom "
3. Удаляем пробелы по краям.

Answer (score 2):

Добрый день. В  C# есть функция [Replace();](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Можно например так, хотя немного не рационально если большая строка:

```
        string str = "Top topfase";
        string[] words = str.Split(new Char[] { ' ' });  //так мы поместим в массив каждое слово указывая разделитель - пробел
        //ищем нужное слово и заменяем
        for (int i = 0; i <= words.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (words[i] == "Top")
                words[i] = "Bottom";
        }
        //восстанавливаем слово
        string res ="";
        foreach (string s in words)
            res += s + " "; //вот и результат
```

Но таким способом лучше не пользоваться. Я сам только изучаю C#

Comment: Лучше `Regex.Split(str, @"\W+")`